# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Request failed with status code Forbidden'

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I get the following error when trying to run a client request using RestSharp for realtime stock data retrieval:

"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Request failed with status code Forbidden'"

Here is the xaml code I have so far:

```html
<Grid x:Name="g" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbox" Header="Please enter symbol to lookup:" PlaceholderText=" Type symbol here... " InputScope="Text" TextChanged="{x:Bind textChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Button x:Name="b" Grid.Row="1" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="stockData" ></Button>

    <StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Frame x:Name="f" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Here is the code-behind I have so far:

```html
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using RestSharp;



namespace Realtime_Stock_Data_Lab
{
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private string _symbol;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void textChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
            _symbol = t.Text;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(_symbol));
        }

        public void stockData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new RestClient($"https://api.polygon.io/v2/last/nbbo/{_symbol.ToUpper()}?apiKey=<_API_Key_>");
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            var response = client.Get(request);
            f.Content = response.Content;
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

The app just runs a simple text box for input, the symbol text input updates the "_symbol" string, and the button click runs the client request with "_symbol" set to uppercase for query and retrieval of realtime stock data.  Does anyone have any idea on how to get this error resolved?

Comment: It seems like you cannot call the polygon.io endpoint. Have you tried calling the endpoint directly and gotten a response? Have you debugged this and saw polygon.io returning a 403? The api key might be the issue

Comment: How do I call the polygon.io endpoint?

Comment: Using Postman maybe? Most of the code you have shown is not relevant to the question

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I tried Postman, it worked great.  However, I got the following error when sending a daily open/close request for MSFT:  "403 Forbidden, The request was a legal request, but the server is refusing to respond to it.  Unlike a 401 unauthorized response, authenticating will make no difference."  Might this mean I need a paid subscription for the realtime data, or is there something else I can do in C# to get this working?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble.  After further testing I found that the provider requires a paid subscription for realtime data requests.  Thanks for your help anyway.  :)